# Trying to send an email with js/php. Says success but no email sends

Tags: javascript, php, html, email

I have stared at this thing for long enough I figured it was time to post a question about this. I have code taken from samples that when I fill the form out and click send it says it is a success but no email actually ever gets sent to the mailbox.

**Javascript**

```
$(function() { 
 $("input,textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({
    preventSubmit: true,
    submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
        // additional error messages or events
    },
    submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
        // get values from FORM
        var name = $("input#name").val();
        var email = $("input#email").val();
        var phone = $("input#phone").val();
        var message = $("textarea#message").val();
        var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
        // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
        if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
            firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: "././mail/contact_me.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                name: name,
                phone: phone,
                email: email,
                message: message
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function() {
                alert("test1");
                // Success message
                $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
                $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                    .append("</button>");
                $('#success > .alert-success')
                    .append("<strong>Your message has been sent. </strong>");
                $('#success > .alert-success')
                    .append('</div>');

                //clear all fields
                $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("test2");
                // Fail message
                $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                    .append("</button>");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').append("<strong>Sorry " + firstName + ", it seems that my mail server is not responding. Please try again later!");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
                //clear all fields
                $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
            },
        })
    },
    filter: function() {
        return $(this).is(":visible");
    },
});

$("a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab("show");
});
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
// Check for empty fields
if(empty($_POST['name'])        ||
   empty($_POST['email'])       ||
   empty($_POST['phone'])       ||
   empty($_POST['message']) ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
    echo "No arguments Provided!";
    return false;
   }

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

// Create the email and send the message
$to = 'myemail@something.com';
$email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nMessage:\n$message";
$headers = "From: myemail@something.com\n"; // This is the email address the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address"; 
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;            
?>
```

**HTML**

```
<form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name *" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email *" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Phone *" id="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Your Message *" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                            <div id="success"></div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xl">Send Message</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: check the result of the mail function. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: And add logging in the php file to see if your JS code even makes it there (above the first if).

Comment: Are you using ssmtp? would u please provide the configuration of your mail server?

Comment: I am not sure this project is was created and is hosted by c9.io. Not sure if their is a mail server configured.

Answer (score 0):

well first of all, your success/error handling in javascript is only checking if the ajax call was successful,
second - you are not checking if mail function succeeded and return true in any case

it should be

```
if( mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) )
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

after that you check the returned value in ajax callback

```
  success: function(response){
    if(response === true){
        /* do stuff */
    }
}
```

I've uploaded this code to my server and everything seems to work fine, XAMPP on the other hand - didnt send the mail. I think I just forgot to configure the mail part, It's been a while since i used mail function locally

Comment: `return mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);` would be a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have php set up to send mail. I had some trouble with mail() not working. The function returned true, but nothing was happening.

This may help: https://serverfault.com/questions/119105/setup-ubuntu-server-to-send-mail